# Regex pattern to change the color in all occurences

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

```
"<p><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Beautifully hand designed brochure with arresting imagery created by the designers</span><em style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> eminem.</em></p>"
```

```
"<p><span style="color: rgb(105,105,105);">Beautifully hand designed brochure with arresting imagery created by the designers</span><em style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> eminem.</em></p>"
```

I want to change the rgb color (128,128,128) by making a script. please help me to solve this

Comment: But you don't need a regex to chage color, you can change the color of the element with .css('color', new_color). Do you need the regex because of some reason?

Comment: because I need to replace in all occurrences of that particular string. if there is any other ways also. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript code to change all span to the preferred rgb color:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span').forEach(element => {
  element.style.color = 'rgb(128,128,128)';
});
```

```html
<p><span style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Beautifully hand designed brochure with arresting imagery created by the designers</span><em style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> eminem.</em></p>
<p><span style="color: rgb(105,105,105);">Beautifully hand designed brochure with arresting imagery created by the designers</span><em style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> eminem.</em></p>
```

You can also change 'span' to whatever element you want to select and change.